# How long would the system takes to kill an app after UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification is sent?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am reading the source code of SDImageCache.

Basically every time before an app is killed, upon UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, SDImageCache travels every file cached, identifies those expired and deletes them.

Would the system wait for this kind of class to finish it's job before kill that app? or the deleting process would be rudely interrupted?

Could this class ask for more time to process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That notification is sent immediately after `applicationWillTerminate:` is sent to your app delegate. From [`UIApplicationDelegate`'s documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate:), you have about 5 seconds.

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to perform any tasks and return. If the method does not return before time expires, the system may kill the process altogether.

However, you shouldn't rely on having 5 seconds, and instead use Instruments to improve your code's performance to be as fast as possible. If you're concerned that you'll need more than 5 seconds, you can request more using [`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:).